# MySQL WHERE condition string to array

Tags: mysql, function, where-clause

My statement returns only 1 row

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId IN(downwardsPartnersById(292));
```

because my custom function "downwardsPartnersById" returns a varchar.

Result: "292,307,308"

Condition "IN" requires an array: ('292','307','308') but i cant't use a string or it will break the string at the first "," and only returns the first row with UserId 292.

I tried to use FIND_IN_SET function but it seems to not work in WHERE:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(UserId, downwardsPartnersById(292)).
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I don't get it, are you trying to match against one or multiple values?

Comment: can you modify your downwardsPartnersById() function to return something like this "'209','307','308'"

Comment: Don't you mean `FIND_IN_SET` instead of `FIELD_IN_SET`? This _should_ work.

Comment: Sorry. I meant FIND_IN_SET. Still not work. I'm using MySQL. I Can modifiy my function, but I think it will not be possible to return a set of varchar, or?

Comment: But it _should_ work, [I just tested it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc22b/1). Could you post some sample data? Also, are you sure your function returns the string as you say it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` *does* require a set, and what you have is a delimited string. Ideally, you should make your function return a set instead, but MySQL doesn't support table-valued functions.

So the other option is `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(UserId, downwardsPartnersById(292))
```

...[which should work fine in your case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc22b/1). If it doesn't, then:

- either the function's return value is not the expected
- or your table contains no relative data in the `UserId` column.

Comment: It's not work. Is it possible my column "UserId" is not able to do this? It's INT810) UN NN zerofill PK AI using utf8 on InnoDB

Comment: Works! my FN + SP needs to use Zerofill on there elements to compaire right :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your using a stored procedure to return a string of IDs, you can use a sub-query in your IN statement.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId IN(SELECT ID FROM <YourTable> WHERE PartnerID=292);
```

or whatever your stored procedure is doing.

Another option is to have your stored procedure return a list instead of a varchar. This is outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4207881/2543917

Comment: Not possible. my fn calls a SP which is recursive to list all childs even if there is more then one level.